# Remove function doesn't work jQuery

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I'm trying to use this jQuery function:

```
$('a').filter(function(index) { 
    return $(this).text() === oEvent.getSource().getTarget().split("/")[0]; 
}).nextAll().remove();
```

This function is called when I press a link in a toolbar and I want to remove all next link in the toolbar but it doesn't work. When I press the link it seems to work because all next link are removed but instantly they reappear. I'm using SAP UI5 and I hate it. Someone has a solution or any other ideas?

Comment: If something re-appears after you remove it sounds like the page (or part of its content) is being reloaded after you click the link in the toolbar.

Comment: Can't tell what's going on with this code alone. Have you tried using debugger to step thru and see when the links gets added again?

Comment: I tried to put some breakpoint and till the function is finished the other links are removed but when the function code finish they reappear but i havent used refresh function. During breakpoints the element are removed from dom so i don't understand how is possible that they are reloaded

Comment: it could be some other code you have that adds them back to it, or maybe a css operator

Comment: i have this: <Table
    selectionChange="handleSelectionChange"
    inset="false"
    id="idProductsTable"
    mode="SingleSelectLeft">
    <headerToolbar>
     <Toolbar
      id="idCrumbToolbar" />
    </headerToolbar>   if I click on toolbar element it calls also the funtion handleSelectionChange? because it's the only other function when i modify the toolbar

Comment: @FrancescoAmato Can you update your question with the view and the code how the links are added to the toolbar in the first place? And which version of UI5 are you using (enter `sap.ui.version` in the console)?

Comment: I've solved.. the problem is that jQuery doesn't always works with sapui5. My function works partially because it effectively removes the links but it doesn't remove them from content(i don't know why). To solve the problem i used an inverse for till i found selected link and used removeContent(index) to remove effectively from content.

Comment: This is nonsense. Why should jQuery not work with UI5. You just have to use the API provided by UI5 to manipulate your objects instead of manipulating the DOM with jQuery directly. Point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you are assuming SAPUI5 simply places objects in the DOM and then you can manipulate them directly. This is not the case - think of the SAPUI5 library more like a controller that moves objects onto and off the DOM all the time. Each control has a `rerender` method that will basically overwrite any changes you have made to the DOM directly.

I think you would be better off simply using SAPUI5 controls (in this example the `sap.m.Link` control) and then calling the `setVisible` method to hide those controls you want to disappear. You could also bind the `visible` property of the controls to a model and manipulate the model to show/hide the controls as well.